# a long time vs a long time now

Tags: word-usage, difference

> I haven't seen you for a long time.

vs

> I haven't seen you for a long time now.

Are they both correct? Is there any difference (but maybe emphasis) between one and the other?

Comment: For me, there is no difference other than a shade of emphasis. I would probably not notice the difference if you said it to me, but "now" is unnecessary/superfluous. We know you mean now.

Comment: If you add ***now*** after an assertion, this simply implies that the assertion *wasn't* true before (but it is *now*). So in your specific context, including it strongly suggests that there have been few if any previous "long periods" where you haven't seen the addressee (i.e. -  the *current* situation is relatively unusual, in that you usually see the other person fairly often). But there's also an undertone of *...now **that I come to think of it*** (i.e. - not only have I not *seen* you for a long time; I haven't even *thought about* not seeing you). So be careful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, there is no difference other than a shade of emphasis. I would probably not notice the difference if you said it to me, but "now" is unnecessary/superfluous. We know you mean now.